# The layout page could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get the error: **The layout page "_Layout" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Home/_Layout".**

But layout page is at this path: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout"

What can it be for problem?

I just started the project and it look like this:

Controller:

```
namespace Testing.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index view:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>title</h2>
```

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer:]

Comment: **"~/Views/Home/_Layout"** this is indicative. do you have any kind of statement like @layout="~/Views/Home/_Layout" in the View that raises this error?

Comment: No, it's like this: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

Comment: that helps. setting the path as @DarinDimitrov pointed out should fix it

Comment: Is this a flaw in the _ReSharper_ Add-View shortcut, which generated the line Layout = "_Layout";

Comment: Little Late to the game, but I have had the same problem in the past when I renamed a layout or changed it. I have not found a way to fix this aside from recreating the view with the correct layout referenced from the start.

Comment: I'm getting this error only when publishing to local http, running well on ISS express.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure that in your `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file you have set the correct path:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Also if in your views you are overriding the layout ensure that the proper path is specifid for this layout. And in addition to that there could be some server side code which is setting the layout (such as custom action filters, or the `ViewResult` overload which allows to specify a layout, ...).

---

UPDATE:

You seem to have set the Layout like this:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
    Layout = "_Layout"; 
}
```

You need to specify the location to the layout as absolute path:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But an even better way is to get rid of this Layout setting in your `Index` view:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
}
```

Now the value from your `_ViewStart.cshtml` will be used.

Comment: I have listed other possible reasons in my answer. Did you check them all?

Comment: It shouldn't be, I just started the project

Comment: Oh, that's not possible. If you used the default template in Visual Studio you're not gonna tell me that you are getting this error when you run the application without doing any changes, are you? So my question is: what changes did you do to this default template in order to break it? It's hard to help you if you are not providing details. I cannot be reading your mind.

Comment: That's the problem. I created basic MVC 4 project, generated controller with empty read/write Actions and generated Index view. Run project... Boom... Nothing more...

Comment: that was the problem! Thanks! It's a bit confusing that generated code had     Layout = "_Layout"; Thanks again =)

Comment: It's true, although possibly mostly for Resharper users. The first thing you get after creating a new controller and view using the Resharper shortcuts is the line Layout="_Layout" which immediately had me thinking, "Great! It knows where to look for templates and knows what file extension to look for." But it doesn't. So I too got OP's error message out of the box.

Comment: You hit it for me Chris, I use Resharper but usually clear it off and add my own template code-  The trick here for me was I tried to debug to test the navigation before clearing it off- It cost me an hour or so before this thread gave me the duh! moment.

Comment: I noticed that when I use the option 'Create Razor view with layout' when rightclicking on the return View(); statement in the Controller class, that Visual studio automatically creates the @{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
    Layout = "_Layout"; 
} statement in the view, without adding '.cshtml' to the layout file. Is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem appear once i had deployed my service, but could not replicate locally. For me the issue was that the View had **None** set for its build action. So the error was correct in that the file did not exist on the server, despite it existing in the repository.

Solution to fix this:

1. Right click on missing view and open *Properties* [View Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTqpT.png)
2. Ensure Build Action is set to *Content*
3. Update csproj file to match new Build Action. [.csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZla0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using the wrong tilde can also produce this error.

Make sure you use the tilde "~" on your keyboard.

If you copied the code from a book, the tilde could be an invalid character (note that there are more than one tilde in Unicode).

Answer (score 1):

In your case i cant see the `_layout.cshtml` .. you have to give the correct path to the `_layout.cshtml` file.. if the file is exist in the same views folder with the `_ViewStart.cshtml` no need to add `.cshtml` part.
but if you reference it from another folder make sure to add `.cshtml` part like this `_layout.cshtml` ..

so you have to add correct path whare the `_layout.cshtml` located. like below

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
    Layout = "_Layout"; 
}
```

the index view will be like that

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with Accepted Answer? Don't need to repeat the same!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a PartialView and now you want to return View instead of PartialView in your ActionResult Method.