# The layout view '~/Admin/_ViewStart.cshtml' could not be located

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There is an area called admin and I get an error although there is an _ViewStart.cshtml file

[image: file structure]

_ViewStart.cshtml content this way

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Picture of the Error I Received

[image: Picture of the Error I Received]

Comment: Issue is probably a reference to a layout in one of the files. Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923718/the-layout-page-could-not-be-found

Comment: I could not solve my own problem by looking at that issue

Comment: Double check the view you are trying to open, does it reference a specific _Layout file Does that layout file reference a specific _ViewStart file?

Comment: I solved the problem when I read your subject more carefully. @Andrew Thank you!

Comment: Great I will just put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is probably a reference to a layout in one of the files that is trying to load.

Double check the view you are trying to open, does it reference a specific _Layout file? Does that layout file reference a specific _ViewStart file?